# Persist query params during all user navigation in a react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

When a user access my website, he may bring some query params, which he should carry with him during all visit. I used Routes to create the paths.

For example:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/component1" component={Component1} />
  <Route exact path="/component2" component={Component2} />
</Switch>
```

The Component1 or 2 may be another router with sub paths, and eventually the user can be redirected to another project and he must bring the params with him.

For example:

User access `mysite.com/welcome?source=google`, in this project he chooses to go to the product section which has the path `mysite.com/product`, and should take the `source=google` with him, like `mysite.com/product?source=google`. Let's say I have another react project that is focused on signup, and he goes to `signup.mysite.com/`, if he uses the buttons inside the project he should go to `signup.mysite.com/?source=google`.

I saw some solutions where it is recommended to implement an `URLSearchParams` in all components, but it may be many, and there will be a lot of repeated code.

Comment: Do you need it to be visible to the user at all times or it's ok if the information is only available to you?

Comment: The query params are only important for me, user does not need to know about it.

Comment: Just added a anwser :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the fact that the user does not need to know about the parameters, i suggest you do the following:

1. Add a URLSearchParams inside an useEffect in your App.js (or wherever the routes are declared), so you can retrieve the source value from the url.
2. If the param exists, save it in localStorage or [Context](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/context.html).
3. Retrieve it whenever you need and delete when you don't need it anymore.

Note: It's nice to retrieve and remove the information because the user can navigate through your website and sometimes share a link with another user – which will use the same source value from the original user and may conflict with some business-rule

Comment: Thank you Rafael, but in the case where the user goes to another app, like signup. By another app I mean like a mono repo where I have a react app for a landing page, and another react app for the logged area, in this solution if the user arrives by the landing page app, and goes to logged area, will I be able to access this localStorage or Context that was created by the landing page app?

Comment: Yeah, localStorage is available for the entire origin (window.location.origin). You can try by setting some value in a key and taking a look at how it's stored in your browser in Developer Tools > Storage > Local Storage (In Google Chrome). You can read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API

Comment: Please remember to select my answer if it solved your problem and let me know if you have more questions